# Wordpress images in a subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WP install in a subdirectory, but in my page templates and php files, I refer to the document root, so it reverts back to the main directory to load image files.   Is there a quick way like with an .htaccess file to have the images redirected to the subdirectory first?

```
MainURL: mysite.com/wordpress1
CPURL: mysite.com/wordpress1

<img src="/images/image1.jpg">

I want the image to load from: "/wordpress1/images/image1.jpg"
```

I don't want to manually hardcode the subdirectory just in case I don't need to use it in the future. I want it to be universal...

Comment: You're asking - slightly - the wrong question. .htaccess isn't the best way to do this. I've added an answer that outlines the Wordpress functions for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .htaccess is not the best way to do this - there are a range of functions that Wordpress defines in order for you to get the correct directories. It's designed for circumstances just as this: where the folder Wordpress ends up in could be very different!

This function will always return the site URL: [home_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/), eg: `http://example.com/wordpress`

So you can reference your images like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/images/image1.jpg">
```

There's also a site_url() function, the [differences are explained in this question/answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20294/whats-the-difference-between-home-url-and-site-url).

Also useful if you're developing a theme, this function will always return the theme directory root: [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/), eg: `http://example.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme`

There's a full list of functions that return various URLs and server paths for your Wordpress install at [this Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories).

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you're using absolute paths in your templates ther's something wrong in how you write your templates, BTW here is a simple rewrite rule

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ /subdir/wp-content/uploads/$1
```

Replace `subdir` with your sub directory, this example is made on the uploads subdirectory of wp-content, but you can also apply to other subdirs.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote since the answer was clear: **Is there a quick way like with an .htaccess file to have the images redirected to the subdirectory first?** and what I gave (before I mentioned the wrong approach) is a redirect rule for an .htaccess...